# Bitmap.SetPixel not setting the correct color

Tags: c#, .net

I have a bitmap, and I am trying to apply an alpha channel to it. This alpha exists in a binary file, and I am able to read all of the bytes in it and get the correct values. Color.FromArgb also gives the right color when I test it. However, when I call SetPixel on my bitmap, it doesn't work - it acts like nothing happened. What am I doing wrong?

If it is relevant, the bitmap is created from a stream using SharpZibLib.

```
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
         var c = imageData.GetPixel(x, y);
         var a = alphaMask[y*width + x];

         imageData.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(a, c));
    }
}
```

**(OLD) Final Answer: (Has side effects, see new final solution)**
It turns out that I needed the speed from CodeInChaos's answer, but his answer did not work until I also used Vitaliy's suggestion and did `MakeTransparent()` before I locked the bits.

**(NEW) Final Answer**
Using `MakeTransparent()` on a 24-bit bitmap actually has some undesirable consequences. `MakeTransparent()` looks for a specific light-grey color to make the transparent color in the bitmap. If this color does not exist, then it chooses the closest color, and sets it to ARGB (00,00,00,00). If you then make this non-transparent by changing the alpha to 255, you get black pixels on your image wherever the 'closest' color to the light grey is. I suggest using the following method to "upgrade" your image if you need to add an alpha channel:

```
            var bmp = new Bitmap(imageStream);
            var rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);

            var upgradedBmp = bmp.Clone(rect, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            bmp.Dispose();
```

This adds the alpha channel without replacing a color to be transparent, and minimal memory usage in the long run.

Comment: What format are you saving the image as?

Comment: The image is not being saved, its all being done in memory so it can be previewed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps a pre-multiplied alpha vs non pre-multiplied alpha issue.

But I'd recommend avoiding `GetPixel`/`SetPixel` completely. They are *very very* slow. Lock the image data and work directly on it.

Comment: If I am trying to set the alpha on each of these bytes (using LockBits), I am modifying the first byte, followed by every third byte, right? I am following the example given here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d.aspx

Comment: You need to modify every 4th byte, since you have 4 channels with 8 bits each.

Comment: There's a good chance that alpha channel is the fourth byte.  Should be easy to test.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I still dont have it quite right in my code, but I can tell this is the right track. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

*Before calling SetPixel() you need to call MakeTransparnet().*

See [VB .NET picture GetPixel & SetPixel: Include alpha?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610970/vb-net-picture-getpixel-setpixel-include-alpha)

Comment: Yours did work as well, but I needed something faster (I may be using some very large images for spritesheet animation later)

Comment: Huh. It turns out that I need to use your suggestion for making it transparent as well to have an alpha for each pixel as well. I wish I could accept both of your answers, since they bot got me there.